# chrome.fileSystem on files/folders inside the app/extension

Tags: google-chrome, file-io, google-chrome-app

I am working on a Chrome App where I need the users to open files in a directory. For his own files, I can offer them a dialog through

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry
```

which works well. However that seems to limit me to the "Downloads" directory and Google Drive on my Chromebook. I would also like to ship some files with the application itself, so the files/folders would be located *inside* the app package. Is it possible to access these files through the fileSystem API?

I would not need the user to choose the files from a dialogue, it would be enough if I could get a handle to these files and offer to display them on the click of a button through my app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read included files using `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(directoryEntry) {})`

Comment: thanks! I only found chrome.runtime.getURL, and it kept returning paths that did not exist. chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry showed me that apparently all my files inside the package are in a subfolder /crxfs/ which they never mention on the docs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only applies when you access them using getPackageDirectoryEntry.

Comment: ... which i do :) Turned out to be not a problem in the end, directoryEntry returns everything i needed. Thanks for the help!